# Session Codeigniter - Automatic Check data

Tags: php, codeigniter

What would be the best way to work with sessions CodeIgniter to do the following ?

I have users with a role and a company that are stored in a database.

I want identify user role and company without do :

```
if($roles == 'Editor'): 

// do something

endif;
```

In each controller or method.

**Example :**

If users is logged a function in header checks that and if not it redirects to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an authentication library? [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) is a good solution and if you need roles you can try the [Tank Auth with Roles](https://bitbucket.org/mtsandeep/tank-auth-with-roles/wiki/Home) library.

Also, if you want to check if a user is logged in you can add the code to the constructor of your controller.

```
function __construct() {
    // Check the user is logged in / roles / etc
    if( ! $roles == 'Editor' ) { redirect('welcome'); }
}
```

Just add this code inside the class and it will run for any page within that controller.

Comment: I tend to keep my "is logged in" check in MY_Controller.php's constructor, and then have all other controllers extend it. No need to copy paste the "is logged in" code on every single controller's constructor.